# Access environment variables in Angular e2e Protractor tests

Tags: angular, protractor

Is there a way to wire up the environment settings for an ng app to its protractor e2e counterpart?

```
   "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
        "build": "environments/environment.build.ts",
        "uat": "environments/environment.uat.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }

...

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

...

var ev = environment.apiBaseUrl;
```

I could probably repeat myself and tap into the Protractor config, but who likes doing that?